# How to copy image from Google Presentation to local application?

Tags: google-drive, google-slides

I'm trying to copy images from a Google Presentation to a LibreOffice Impress file, but having no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Click to select, CTRL+C, CTRL+V isn't working?

Comment: This is much easier now thanks to Keep Notepad. See the reply below using the new Google Slides feature "save to Keep Notepad"

Answer (score 29):

Did you try grabbing the URL via the Network panel in developer tools? I was able to get the URLs for images I needed by:

1. Opening Developer Tools in Chrome (Cmd+Opt+I)
2. Selecting the "Network" tab (you may need to refresh the presentation)
3. Clicking the little "filter" icon (the third icon from the top left)
4. Clicking "Images" to show only images
5. Clicking "Preview" to make sure you have the correct image
6. Right-click the URL from the preview panel content area and choose to "Open in New Tab"
7. In the new tab, right-click the image and save it

Example:
[image]

Comment: Your answer was the best. Thank you!!

Comment: Does this always get the highest resolution version of the image?

Comment: This is much easier now thanks to Keep Notepad. See the reply below using the new Google Slides feature "save to Keep Notepad"

Answer (score 10):

Click on the *Present* button top right corner, this will start the presentation mode.
Right click on the image, use option *Save as* to save the image.

Comment: I do not get this "save" option when I right click the image in presentation mode.

Comment: I went through all that debugger stuff just to find this solution after.

Answer (score 8):

You can download the file as a .pptx, then change the file extension to .zip, decompress it and find the images in the /media folder of the decompressed file.

Comment: brilliant, easiest solution for me, very convenient to be provided a folder with all of the graphics

Comment: This also works with downloading as ODP.

Comment: amazingly simple and doable, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 6):

A much more simple approach is to use the now built-in feature: Google Keep Notepad.

```
Right click image ->  Save to Keep Notepad
```

You can then download from the keep notepad the way you can download any image displayed in your browser.

This not only let's you copy the entire slide, but actual, individual images (at their original resolution).

Comment: This is absolutely the simplest answer.

Comment: This doesn't produce the original resolution.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pain, but you can download the entire file as a pptx, and then open that in LibreOffice, and you can then cut and paste the graphic.

Answer (score 2):

Paste the image in the Google Documents and download as HTML Zipped. Images can be located in the images folder

1. Go to File > Download As > WebPage (HTML, Zipped)
2. Find the image in   the images Folder

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Google drive somehow "encrypt" the image source if you want to copy and paste it into Libre Office Impress. If you do a "Paste Special", the source of the image states "Unknown".

[image]

Also, the same goes for Microsoft Office:

[image]

In conclusion, I do not think it's possible to copy and paste images from Google Drive to Office applications on your workstation. I would however say it is possible to do so between Google Drive applications. The workaround would be either
1. to download the image and insert it as a picture from your computer or
2. Copy the URL of the picture on the Internet (Not Google Drive) and also go to insert > picture > and paste the URL in the location field of the picture.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Middle-clicking or Ctrl+clicking (Cmd+click for OS X) on the image will open it in a new tab. There, it will behave as a regular image that you can save to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Step-1: File >> Download as MS Power Point
Step-2: Open PPT >> right click on the image >> Save image

I used LibreOffice and exported the image successfully, can be done with MS Office too

Answer (score -1):

Go to *File → Download As → JPEG image*.

Comment: But this copies the whole slide, right?

Comment: And this will subsample the image in the presentation, lowering the resolution.

Answer (score -2):

Zoom in as big as you can. <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> to capture the screen. Paste to image editing software, crop and enjoy.

Comment: This will subsample the image, lowering the resolution instead of grabbing the original.